# Create a for-loop that calls a function every x-time in Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, time

I have this data:

```
granularity: 1h
start_time: 2021-4-28T1:1:1.342380Z
end_time: 2021-4-29T1:1:1.342360Z
```

and I want to create a for like this pseudocode:

```
for start_time to end_time:
    call function on each interval of granularity
```

On the given example, I will call a function every 1h from start_time to end_time. The times and the granularity parameters can be changed and are not fixed to the values given on my example. It can be 60 min, 5 seconds...

After thinking a bit and searching on blogs and on Stack Overflow I am not sure how to do this. What can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this using the datetime library, which is standard on most installations of Python. It takes time in seconds so, 60 seconds would be a minute, and 3600 seconds would be an hour.

---

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def alert(time):
    hourtime = time / 60
    print(f"It's Been {time} seconds or {hourtime} Hours")


def timer(seconds, start_time, end_time):
    curr_time = datetime.now()
    formatted_time = curr_time.strftime('%S')
    lasttime = formatted_time
    localtimer = 0 
    while True:
        curr_time = datetime.now()

        formatted_time = curr_time.strftime('%S')
        time_ =  curr_time.strftime('%H%M')


        if int(time_) <= int(end_time) - 1: # Check to see if the current time is less than the end time
            if int(time_) >= int(start_time): # check to see if it's Greater or equal to the start time
                if int(lasttime) != int(formatted_time): # if so it does the alert function every x seconds
                    lasttime = formatted_time
                    print(localtimer) # You can Keep or remove this line it's just for counting how many seconds have gone by.
                    localtimer += 1
                if localtimer == int(seconds):
                    alert(seconds)
                    localtimer = 0
        

timer(seconds=5, start_time=1547, end_time=1548) # It takes time in seconds, start and end time are both in the 24 hr format just without the ":" so instead of 15:44, it would be 1544
```

(Note: the OP corrected me that it needed a start and end time, so I added that in).

---

This is the old code without start and end time:

```
from datetime import datetime

def alert(time):
    hourtime = time / 60
    print(f"It's Been {time} seconds or {hourtime} Hours")


def timer(seconds):
    curr_time = datetime.now()
    formatted_time = curr_time.strftime('%S')
    lasttime = formatted_time
    localtimer = 0 
    while True:
        curr_time = datetime.now()
        formatted_time = curr_time.strftime('%S')
        if int(lasttime) != int(formatted_time):
            lasttime = formatted_time
            print(localtimer) # You can Keep or remove this line it's just for counting how many seconds have gone by.
            localtimer += 1
        if localtimer == int(seconds):
            alert(seconds)
            localtimer = 0


timer(5) # It takes time in seconds so 3600 will be 3600 seconds which is an hour and 5 is 5 seconds, so a minute would be 60 and so on and so forth
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! Actually your algorithm is starting on datetime.now() and not on start time. Also you have not taken in consideration the end time, because the date should be between the start and the end time. But thanks anyway for the idea :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I must've over looked that, I will see if I can fix that one minute.

Comment: @CatarinaNogueira I have added start and end time to my original answer.